# How to open page by it link as one html component inside my htlm page without leaving it?

Tags: html, reactjs

in html file i can make

```
<h1> the following page is google page </h1>
<pageElement linkForThePage='google.com'/>
```

how can I open any page inside the marginal page without leaving it? is there an HTML element that do this.
in case you did not understand what I mean: I want to open other pages like google authentication as a component (like opop up but I don't want to make a popup) in my original page.

Comment: you can load a page in `div` container using the `load()` method.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov — React doesn't have a `load()` method … and jQuery's `load()` method won't work because [the same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) won't allow it.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov React is Single Page App

Comment: Yes. I didn't pay attention to hashtag `reactjs`. Thanks.

Comment: @All Does my answer help you dear Friend :) I would be more than happy if it does :) God Bless You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  I had come up with the `iframe` approach to load a website within the component. **However**, **all the websites with authentication pages like google, facebook will block framing.**

You need to use `iframe` within your Component That you wanted to link to.

```
 const MyWebSite = ({siteName})=>{
  return(
   <iframe src={siteName} title="My Site Name">
   </iframe>
   )
 }
```

Then from Parent Component Use this Component.

```
<MyWebsite siteName="https://aperfectplate.co/" />
```

**Update:** While the above website will work and food app is loaded.

**Codesandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/iframe-example-nihyh?file=/src/App.js

But authentication websites will not be loaded within the component with the above approach. For example if you try below code. It wouldn't load google.com.

```
<MyWebsite siteName="https://www.google.com/" />
```

That's what I feel can be done. You may improve it later using React Router. You can make it behave like a link also. This idea could be used to build on top of :)

Comment: That won't work. Google (and Google authentication) block framing.

Comment: Is it. I mean the questioner simply wants to know way  in a SPA. We don't have to specifically use google.com

Comment: Quoting the question: "I want to open other pages like google authentication as a component". You **do** have to specifically use google.com

Comment: Like google :) is mentioned. Leave google aside ... What about general scenario Dear Quentin :) Even I want to learn. There is no shame learning

Comment: In the general case, most pages **like** google authentication will block framing because they are authentication pages and authentication pages generally block framing.

Comment: And the question is focusing on a subset of them and gives a specific example.

Comment: What about the title of the question :)

Comment: The title is supposed to be a short summary of the problem. There isn't room to put all the nuances of the problem in it.  The body provides additional detail. That is why you shouldn't ignore the body of the question and answer the title alone.

Comment: Sure Mate. Iframe don't support  in general. Authenticated  sites will not load in iframe and will block it ... Thanks for your advise :)

Comment: Shall I update my Answer and include the authentication issue there also

Comment: @Quentin : Respected Quentin, Please have a look at my updated answer. Could it help anyone in future :) If yes then I'll keep this answer. If not I will delete it, as I don't want answers that aren't helpful for developers :) Thank U